# How to Update mysql using ajax and redirect page after update success?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How to Update mysql using ajax and redirect page after update success ?

When click link `update` after update mysql redirect to `member.php`

index.php

```
<a onClick="update()" id="1">update<a>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.clickable').on('click', function() {
        var data = {
            id: $(this).data('id')
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'update.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

update.php

```
<?php
include('connect.php'); 
$id = $_POST['id'];
mysql_query ("UPDATE member SET number = '' WHERE id=$id");
?>
<script language="javascript">
    window.location.href = "member.php"
</script>
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting now?

Comment: just place the ``location.href`` in the ``success`` function from the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

First add class to get on click

```
<a onClick="update();" id="1" class="clickable">update<a>
```

Then return response:-

```
$query = mysql_query ("UPDATE member SET number = '' WHERE id=$id");

if($query)
echo 'success';
```

Then success

```
success: function(response) {
    window.location.href = "member.php";
}
```

So full code will be:-

```
<a onClick="update()" id="1" class="clickable">update<a>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    function update(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'update.php',
            data: {id: $(".clickable").attr('id')},
            success: function(response) {
                 //$('.clickable').hide(); // hide not possible on redirect
                 window.location.href = "member.php";
            }
        });
    }
</script>

update.php

<?php
include('connect.php'); 
$id = $_POST['id'];
$query = mysql_query ("UPDATE member SET number = '' WHERE id=$id");
if($query)
  echo 'success';
?>
```

Comment: after success i want to hide `update` link and show `was updates` link 
can i do that thank

Comment: not possible on redirect i have updated code remove redirect and use hide code in success

Comment: i use your code for update and redirect not work , could you please give me some code.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX with JSON answer, that way you'll be able to redirect whenever you want without problem, and use objects from PHP to your JS flow:

You don't have to use js events on your DOM, only with your js you'll be able to achieve it, and it'll make your code more reusable, as it'll make it free from hardcoded variables:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a class="clickable" href="update.php" id="1">update</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.clickable').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var link = $(this);
                var data = {
                    id: link.attr('id')
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: link.attr('href'),
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);

                        if (response.result) {
                            console.log('All done!');
                        } else {
                            console.log('Something went wrong!');
                        }

                        if (response.redirect != 'undefined') {
                            window.location.href = response.redirect;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then, in your PHP, you'll have to give back the answer as a JSON value, to get it:

**update.php**

```
<?php
include('connect.php'); 
$id = $_POST['id'];
$data = array();
if ( mysql_query ("UPDATE member SET number = '' WHERE id=$id") ) {
    $data['result'] = true;
    $data['redirect'] = 'http://example.com/redirect_to_ok_place';
} else {
    $data['result'] = false;
    $data['redirect'] = 'http://example.com/redirect_wrong_result';
}

echo json_encode($data); die();
?>
```

Note that your AJAX file must finish and echo your response if you want to get the values from PHP, and you MUST have a well formed json, so, if nothing is showed, check with console what values you're getting back, and if you echoed something previously.

To finish, it also important to point out that you MUST NOT USING MYSQL_QUERY PHP FUNCTIONS!! is deprecated, and it's a huge security hole. Use PDO or, if nothing else may be done, mysqli extension. Your code is ready for MySQL injection, so check for it here in SO to avoid it.

Comment: i tested but in update.php not get `$_POST[id]` value. and after success your code not redirect but on;y echo text.

Comment: exactly, you're getting text, I suppose something like {result:1;redirect:'http:...'}, which is a JSON object that your JS code will be able to read. Could you paste what are you getting? And I'll modify the js, give me a second...

Comment: My mistake, as update is a link element, you're sending directly to update.php. You have to prevent default behaviour to avoid it, check the updated code

Comment: Another mistake: I forgot to specify that is a JSON request, so your code is able of taking it. I checked it, and you will get the id in your sistem from the POST. If you want to check, just delete from update.php the mysql_query and echo $data json_encoded array, and you'll have it working, XD

Comment: it's work , but when i open link in a new tab it's will access to update.php , how to do with open a new tab?

Comment: that would be client programing: try, instead of window.location.href = response.redirect; using the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make duplicate requests. just change your update.ph as below:

```
<?php
include('connect.php'); 
$id = $_POST['id'];
mysql_query ("UPDATE member SET number = '' WHERE id=$id");

header('Location: http://www.example.com/member.php'); // Here you need to give your actual path where you want to redirect.

exit;
?>
```